# How to make a program wait for a button press

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created an android application and i would like to pause the running code and wait for a button press.

For example lets say i have 3 buttons, Button1 Button2 Button3.
I would like to do :

```
int a=0;
// do something
.. wait for button press..
if(button1 is pressed) a=1;
else if(button2 is pressed) a=2;
else if(button3 is pressed) a=3;
// continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how Android application development works, or application development on most modern UI frameworks (where by "modern" I mean "written in the last 25 years"). As with most other platforms and UI frameworks, Android's widget framework is event-driven. Please modify your algorithm to be able to be handled via the `onClick()` methods of your various buttons.

Comment: i already though of having a continue() method on button click but that tears apart my code solution so i would like to know if such option was available, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I would do it:

First, have your activity implement onClickListener

```
public class CustomButton extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

The OnClickListener has 1 method to override,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
      case r.id.button1:
        a=1;
        break;
      case r.id.button2:
        a=2;
        break;
      case r.id.button3:
        a=3;
        break;
}
```

Note that r.id.button1 etc refers to the ID's you give to the buttons in your layout file